Как реализовать перемещение персонажа по вертикальным поверхностям и вверх ногами?
Игрок управляет персонажем, который должен перемещаться по негоризонтальным поверхностям.
Видел идею использовать нормали объекта, но у меня они будут не правильными фигурами, как стены, а более сложными моделями, и как получать нормали у них я не знаю.
Пробовал притягивать персонажа к точке под ним, найденной с помощью raycast, но это не всегда корректно работает, и возникают проблемы со вращением персонажа.
Может у кого есть идеи, как реализовать такую механику?

Ну для начала гужно компенсировать гравитацию движка, то есть выяснить как она на движке работает и дать отрицательную силу. Затем повесить игрока в воздухе и проверить, что его никуда не притягивает и он не дёргается. Затем дополнительно реализовать точно то же самое, что вы делали при компенсации гравитации, только в направлении нормали к поверхности. Если физических объектов кроме игрка нет, то гравитацию движка можно просто выключить, тогда компенсировать не придётся.
